# Refresh a listbox to display new values

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

This is a newb question so I'm sorry.

I'm filling out my text box with values Im grabbing on line and passing them to the listbox like so:

```
        // textBox1.Text = test.ToString();
        string[] names = result.Split('|');
        foreach (string name in names)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(name);
        }
```

However I'm trying to click on a folder and have the files displayed from there be shown in my listbox1. THis is what I've tried:

```
   using (var testy = new WebClient())
        {

            test = testy.DownloadString("http://server.foo.com/images/getDirectoryList.php?dir=test_folder");
            string[] names1 = test.Split('|');
            foreach (string name in names1)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.Add(name);
                listBox1.Update();
            }

        }
```

But all that happens is that my listbox empties and doesn't get refreshed. How can I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2):

before you do anything else remove the clear and update from the foreach

```
  listBox1.Items.Clear();
  foreach (string name in names1)
  {

     listBox1.Items.Add(name);

  }
  listBox1.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

your lines

```
        foreach (string name in names1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add(name);
            listBox1.Update();
        }
```

makes it that for every string you are removing ever other item in the list.

i'm pretty sure that's not what you want

Answer (score 0):

Use a BindingSource

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
List<string> names1 = new List();
bs.DataSource = names1;
comboBox.DataSource = bs;

   using (var testy = new WebClient())
    {

        test = testy.DownloadString("http://server.foo.com/images/getDirectoryList.php?dir=test_folder");
        names1.AddRange(test.Split('|'));
        bs.ResetBindings(false);

    }
```

The BindingSource will take care of everything for you.